# Objects not staying in ArrayList

Tags: java

I am writing a program that supposed to allow the user to enter a course for school. However, a couple problems.

- First, I can't for some reason get it to take more than one word for the courseTitle. If two words are entered, it throws an error.
- Second, it's not "permanently" adding these classes to an arraylist?

Here's how it's supposed to work:

> Please select from the following options:
>
> 1. Add a course
> 2. Add a student to a course
> 3. View available courses
> 4. Exit from system

This isn't being stored to a file, so I'm not sure how to keep the courses in memory. Anyway, here's what I've got.

```
    if(userChoice==1)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the Course Number: ");
        int courseNum=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Course Title: ");
        String courseTitle=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the Max Number Allowed Students: ");
        int courseMaxSize = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Course Number is "+courseNum);
        System.out.println("Course Title is "+courseTitle);
        System.out.println("Max Number of Students is "+courseMaxSize);
        SchoolClass nc = new SchoolClass(courseNum,courseTitle,courseMaxSize);
        ArrayList<SchoolClass> courseArr=new ArrayList<SchoolClass>();
        courseArr.add(nc);
        System.out.println(courseArr.get(0).getCourseTitle()+" "+courseArr.get(0).getCourseNumber()+" "+courseArr.get(0).getMaxStudents());
        System.out.println(courseArr.size());
```

My `SchoolClass` class looks like this:

```
int courseNumber,maxPeers;
String course="";
public SchoolClass(int courseNum, String courseTitle, int maxStudents)
{
    courseNumber=courseNum;
    course=courseTitle;
    maxPeers=maxStudents;
}
public int getCourseNumber()
{
    return courseNumber;
}
public int getMaxStudents()
{
    return maxPeers;
}
public String getCourseTitle()
{
    return course;
}
```

I have yet to write the code for options 2, 3, 4 obviously. Just looking for a little help to keep me going.

Comment: to read: `Scanner` javadoc (method `nextLine()`), some general stuff about variables and scope

Comment: you are doing `ArrayList<SchoolClass> courseArr=new ArrayList<SchoolClass>();` every time user inputs 1, so the previous arraylist is overwritten. I guess thats what you are asking for in "its not permanently adding these classes". Read about scope of variables.

Comment: You are creating a new local `ArrayList` on (I presume) each loop within your `if` statement, which basically is begin dereferenced when you leave the `if` statement

Answer (score 5):

> First, I can't for some reason get it to take more than one word for the courseTitle.

It is because your code does:

```
    System.out.println("Enter the Course Title: ");
    String courseTitle = scan.next();
```

It should be `scan.nextLine()`. The [documentation for `Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) says that:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

And [`.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) grabs one token.

> Second, it's not "permanently" adding these classes to an arraylist?

It is because your list is created within your `if` branch:

```
if (userChoice == 1) {
    // ....
    ArrayList<SchoolClass> courseArr = new ArrayList<SchoolClass>();
    courseArr.add(nc);
    // ...
}
// "courseArr" does not exist anymore here
```

You have to create your list out of this `if` branch (and probably out of the enclosing loop as well, which grabs the user choice).

Comment: This is what happens if i put nextLine() there:

Comment: Don't put that in a comment, edit your question -- and update your code as well, I suppose you have the list problem fixed, right?

Comment: Enter the Course Number: 
23
Enter the Course Title: 
Enter the Max Number Allowed Students: 

6
Course Number is 23
Course Title is 
Max Number of Students is 6
 23 6
1

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<SchoolClass> courseArr=new ArrayList<SchoolClass>();
if(userChoice==1)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the Course Number: ");
        int courseNum=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Course Title: ");
        String courseTitle=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the Max Number Allowed Students: ");
        int courseMaxSize = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Course Number is "+courseNum);
        System.out.println("Course Title is "+courseTitle);
        System.out.println("Max Number of Students is "+courseMaxSize);
        SchoolClass nc = new SchoolClass(courseNum,courseTitle,courseMaxSize);

        courseArr.add(nc);
        System.out.println(courseArr.get(0).getCourseTitle()+" "+courseArr.get(0).getCourseNumber()+" "+courseArr.get(0).getMaxStudents());
        System.out.println(courseArr.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `SchoolClass` object

```
 SchoolClass sc=new SchoolClass ();
```

set values from your input.

```
 sc.setcourseNumber(2);
 sc.setCourseTitle("Maths");
 sc.setMaxStudents(3);
```

Then create your `ArrayList`

```
 ArrayList<SchoolClass> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

Now set list value

```
 list.add(sc);
```

Comment: This is what the OP is (generally) doing and won't fix their underlying issues